# Updating Matplotlib toolbar when repainted

Tags: matplotlib, wxpython, matplotlib-basemap

I have written a test python program for Matplotlib-Basemap on wxpython using examples found on the internet. A map drawn with Mercator projection when the GUI is launched. On selecting various radio buttons, the user can switch to the desired projection. My problem is this, the Navigation toolbar connected to the matplotlib still seems to contain the data for the first image. No amount of refreshing, updating or realizing is correcting this.
When I press the zoom button, the first image is getting zoomed. The current image is not being updated. ANy help or suggestion would be welcome. Here's my code:

```
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from wx._windows import StatusBar
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')

from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import NavigationToolbar2Wx as Toolbar

import wx



class BasemapPanel(wx.Panel):
def __init__(self, parent,projectionString):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

    self.reDraw('merc',72.5,18.4)


def draw(self):
    t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
    s = sin(2 * pi * t)
    self.axes.plot(t, s)

def reDraw(self,projectionString,testLon,testLat):

    self.figure = Figure(None,dpi=75)

    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
    self.axes = self.figure.add_axes([0,0,1,1],frameon=False)
    self.toolbar = Toolbar(self.canvas)
    self.toolbar.Realize()


    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)

    sizer.Add(self.toolbar, 0 , flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, border=10)
    self.SetSizer(sizer)
    self.canvas.Refresh(True)
    self.Layout()
    self.map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-179, llcrnrlat=-80, urcrnrlon=179,
                       urcrnrlat=80, projection=projectionString, lat_1=18.2, lat_2=45,
                       lon_0=-95, resolution='c', area_thresh=10000,ax=self.axes)
    self.map.drawcoastlines()
    self.map.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')
    self.map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
    self.map.drawcountries()
    self.map.drawstates()

    lon, lat = testLon, testLat # Location 
    xpt,ypt = self.map(lon,lat)
    lonpt, latpt = self.map(xpt,ypt,inverse=True)
    self.map.plot(xpt,ypt,'bo')  # plot a blue dot there
    self.axes.text(xpt+100000,ypt+100000,'Location (%5.1f,%3.1f)' % (lonpt,latpt))
    self.toolbar.update()        




class MainPanel(wx.Panel):


def __init__(self, parent):
   wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

   font = wx.SystemSettings_GetFont(wx.SYS_SYSTEM_FONT)


   self.vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)


   hbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
            # Radio Boxes

   radioListOfProjections = ["merc" ,  "kav7" , "mbtfpq",
    "mill" , "robin",   
  "lcc" , "moll" , "eqdc"]
   self.rb = wx.RadioBox(self, label="Projection ", pos=(20, 210), choices=radioListOfProjections,  majorDimension=3,
                      style=wx.RA_SPECIFY_ROWS)
   self.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBOX, self.OnSelectingProjection, self.rb)
   hbox2.Add(self.rb)
   self.vbox.Add(hbox2,  proportion=1, flag=wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.EXPAND, 
       border=10)
   self.vbox.Add((-1, 10))

   hbox3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
   self.bmPanel = BasemapPanel(self,'merc')
   self.bmPanel.draw()
   self.bmPanel.SetSize((300,300))

   hbox3.Add(self.bmPanel, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
   self.vbox.Add(hbox3, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 
         border=10)

   self.vbox.Add((-1, 35))
   self.SetSizer(self.vbox)       


def OnSelectingProjection(self, e):

    projectionString = self.rb.GetStringSelection()


    self.bmPanel.reDraw(projectionString,45.5,66.6)
    self.bmPanel.draw()

    hbox3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

    hbox3.Add(self.bmPanel, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)

    self.vbox.Add(hbox3, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 
         border=10)

    self.vbox.Add((-1, 35))
    self.SetSizer(self.vbox) 


app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None)
panel = MainPanel(frame)
frame.Size = (650, 700)

frame.Move((400, 250))
frame.Center()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. It was a small error.
 I had to set the Figure on the axes as the one plotted first.

I have to import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In the reDraw method,
Instead of setting 
self.figure = Figure(None)

set
self.figure(num=1) # The number autoincrements.

This will add the new image to the axes. Therefore to clear the old image, before calling the reDraw Method for setting a new projection, clear the figure as figure.clf().